# (environment-modules) Setting up modulefile for Intel compilers

Tags: compiling, intel, environment-variables, compiler, environment

I am trying to install `openmpi` (not from apt) into my system. I want to use intel compilers (fortran, c and c++) for the compilation. When `./configure` my openmpi folder, **without** `module load intel`, compiler will not be found and the installation will fail. Once, I load intel module environment, I manage to at least configure it. However, when running `make all makefile`, the installation runs but in the end it fails. I've been attempting it ever since and can't figure out why. My guess is my intel modulefile. I am using *Intel Parallel Studio XE Cluster Edition* 2020. I'm not sure if I create my modulefile correctly. Could someone have a look at my modulefile and possibly point out my mistake and fix this problem. Thank you!

This is my intel modulefile:

```
 #%Module1.0#####################################################################
##")
## intel modulefile
##
proc ModulesHelp { } {
    puts stderr "\tAdds Intel compilers to your environment variables,"

}

module-whatis "adds Intel compilers to your environment variables"


set     main_root       /home/hafiz/intel

prepend-path    PATH                $main_root/bin
prepend-path    PATH                $main_root/debugger_2020/gdb/intel64/bin

prepend-path    LIBRARY_PATH        $main_root/lib/intel64
prepend-path    LD_LIBRARY_PATH     $main_root/lib/intel64

prepend-path    CPATH               $main_root/include
prepend-path    CPATH               $main_root/include/intel64

prepend-path    INTEL_LICENSE_FILE      $main_root/licenses

setenv          INTEL_CC_HOME           $main_root
setenv          INTEL_FC_HOME           $main_root
setenv          INTEL_PYTHONHOME        $main_root/debugger_2020/python/intel64
```

Comment: Try to convert psxevars.sh to modulefile with env2 https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/using-environment-modules-with-the-intel-development-tools.html